# Java List forEach Lambda expressional - first elements and loop through all elements

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

I can able to loop through all elements of List like below:

```
userList.forEach(user -> {
    System.out.println(user);
});
```

I want to print the user object only for first element but I should loop for all elements in list.
How to achieve that ?

Comment: Why woud you loop if you don't do anything with the other elements? What do you **actually** want to achieve? Note that forEach() is not the only way to loop over a list. Use what is best for your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply certain logic to first user and continue looping with others then you might use condition to check the first object is the current or not. As I understand from your question, this is what you want

```
userList.forEach(user -> {
    if (userList.get(0) == user)
        System.out.println("This is user with index 0");
    System.out.println(user + " All users including 0");
});
```

As Aomine said in the comments, this might not be great solution for checking the first element of the list each time and might not work correctly if the same user object is repeated on the list so better to separate the logic like this

```
// Do something with the first user only
if(!userList.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(userList.get(0));

// Do some stuff for all users in the list except the first one
userList.subList(1, userList.size()).forEach(user -> {
        System.out.println(user + " All users without 0");
);

// Do some stuff for all users in the list
userList.forEach(user -> {
        System.out.println(user + " All users");
);
```

Another approach using stream

```
// Dealing with first user only
if (!userList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("this is first user: " + userList.get(0));
}
// using stream skipping the first element
userList.stream().skip(1).forEach(user -> {
    System.out.println(user);
});
```

Also you might use iterator approach

```
// getting the iterator from the list
Iterator<String> users = userList.iterator();

// the first user
if(users.hasNext())
    System.out.println("this is first user :" + users.next());

// the rest of the users
users.forEachRemaining(user -> {
    System.out.println(user);
});
```

Comment: seems suboptimal to me, getting the first item in each iteration and then comparing with `user`, I'd do this check before the loop.

Comment: Also using `==` might not work, depending on where the `user` object came from.

Comment: I edited the answer with Aomine comment as my only target was to the logic and answer without looking to more optimal solution. @ÓscarLópez I don't get how this is possible since I'm on the list looping and the object in the iteration should be always the same one as the one on the list.

Comment: "my only target was to the logic and answer without looking to more optimal solution", well another point mentioned by JB Nizet in one of the other answers is that your first approach is not actually correct as it won't work if the same user is in the list several times. But the latest update seems correct.

Comment: @Aomine, I agree but, If the user is in the list multiple times, means same object then I think probably that would be indicated in the question but if the user is repeated as different object, this will still work, after all why I would repeat the user object in the same list !!! so I just think It's more possible the user would be there but not same object and the functionality would be as wanted. However, all this depends on the question and this is not indicated at all, hence, assumptions :)

Comment: Great answer, multiple solutions to the problems opened many doors for similar problem with me. Thank you!

Comment: Using stream is perfect for my case. But I'm not sure if it's better or worse from performance perspective

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're asking, how to print the first object but iterate over the remaining elements and do some other logic with them, in which case you can go with:

```
if(!userList.isEmpty()) System.out.println(userList.get(0));
userList.subList(1, userList.size()).forEach(user -> ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using `for-each`

```
List<String> userList = Arrays.asList("2","3","4");

        IntStream.range(0, userList.size()).forEach(i -> {
            if (i == 0)
                System.out.println(userList.get(i));
            else {
                System.out.println("do other stuff");
            }
        });
```

***O/P:***

```
2
do other stuff
do other stuff
```

Comment: Do you prefer to check something like this:
`for (int i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++){
if (i == 0)`{} //...}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution in JDK9 since you're into lambda expressions:

```
IntStream.range(0, userList.size())
         .peek(i -> {if(i == 0) System.out.println(userList.get(i));})
         .dropWhile(i -> i == 0)
         .forEach(i -> /* some other logic here */ );
```

Personally, and for production code, I'd go with [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51581061/java-list-foreach-lamba-expressional-first-elements-and-loop-through-all-eleme/51581110#51581110) but if you're just having fun with lambda then the above is another approach you could take.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
userList.foreach(user -> {
    If(user == userList.get(0){
        System.out.println(user)
    }
})
```

Comment: seems suboptimal to me, getting the first item in each iteration and then comparing with `user`, I'd do this check before the loop.

Comment: And it won't work is the same user is in the list several times.